# Jquery Autocomplete not working with Input Box from Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a input box which is dynamically added into to page by ajax depend on the user's selection from the drop down list.

```
document.getElementById("input_box").innerHTML ="<input id='ProjectName'/>";
```

The problem is the jQuery's auto complete not working with that input box 'ProjectName'.

```
$(function() {
    $( '#ProjectName' ).autocomplete({
        source: 'data.php'
    });
});
```

It works perfectly, if I hard code  in the same php as jQuery Autocomplete.

Please help.

Comment: You need to make sure the `autocomplete(...)` runs only **after** you add the `#ProjectName` element to your page. Otherwise it's the same as `$('#element-that-doesnt-exists').autocomplete(...)`

Comment: if you are already using jquery, consider using `$("#input_box").html("<input id='ProjectName'/>");` (:, also what Dakel said, make sure the element is created before you try to bind anything

Answer (score 0):

Its because the autocomplete function gets called before the control is generated. please try it like this

```
function setInput(){
    document.getElementById("input_box").innerHTML ="<input id='ProjectName'/>";
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( '#ProjectName' ).autocomplete({
            source: 'data.php'
        });
    })
}<br/>
setInput();
```

and you can also consider setting the `input` using jquery as well.
 `$(#input_box).html("< input id='ProjectName'/>")`

Comment: `#input_box` is missing the quote marks, and `$(document).ready()` inside that function doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the responses. It is really helpful. Actually I don't kno Jquery very much. That's why I don't know how to use  $(#input_box).html("< input id='ProjectName'/>").

Strangely, it does work  by calling onkeyup event from the input box, even the autocomplete get called before the control is generate.

Ajax Generate the input box on the page.

```
<input  id='ProjectName' onkeyup='setInput();'/>
```

My javascript on the page.

```
<script>
function setInput()
{   
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $( '#ProjectName' ).autocomplete({
    source: 'data.php'
    });
    })
}
</script>";
```